# Why won't my div for buttons "center"?

Tags: html, center, centering

My goal is to make my #header div centered. It contains buttons to navigate to different pages. I tried using the `<div align=center>` tag but it just won't work. I just want it to be in the center like everything else on my page.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
 #header ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}
 #header ul li {
position:relative;
float:left;

}
 #header ul li ul li a {
font-size: 12px;
}
 #header ul li a {
display: block;
height: 35px;
width: 90px;
color: #666;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
line-height: 35px;
text-align: center;
}
   #header ul li ul {
position: absolute;
top: 31px;
visibility: hidden;
}
    #header ul li a:hover {
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
}
    #header ul li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
}
#header {
width:100%;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
text-align:left;

}

 body {
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
text-align: center;
}
 </style>
 </head>

<body  bgcolor="#E6F7F4">
 <center>
   <p><img src="othlogo.gif"/><br />
   </p>
 <div id="header" align="right" >
  <ul>
<li><a href"blog.html">Blog</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
<li><a href"blog.html">More</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="more.html">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">Domestic</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
<li><a href"blog.html">Option3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="more.html">Psychology</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">Map</a></li>

    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
<li><a href"blog.html">About</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. It's on align=right at the moment, but align=center won't do anything. I feel like something is preventing it from centering.

Comment: You can use `margin:auto` to center... not a `center` tag or `align`, they are deprecated. http://jsfiddle.net/ would be a good way to let people see your code and help you fix it. Yes you have a `margin:auto` on it but there are other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin: auto` to center `#header` as long as it has a width set on it.

Comment: THANKS! It worked:

#header {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url(toolbar.gif);
}